# Unable to Expose Daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS in LINUX RHEL

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I am unable to Expose Daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS in Linux RHEL.

I have added below in docker.service, reloaded the docker daemon and restarted docker service
"ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock -H tcp://10.75.149.34:2375"

where as on checking service status it doesn't reflect here.
Main PID: 4671 (dockerd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─4671 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2736

I am new to docker and unable to understand what went wrong.

Please help me on this.

Comment: **Do not try to enable this configuration.**  It will allow _anyone_ on the network who can reach your host to trivially root it.  Google "Docker cryptojacking" for some real-world examples.

Comment: Thanks David this is actually in one of the requirements, I updated in docker.service file still it’s not getting enabled. Is there anyway I can enable it or anything missed in my approach.